# Problem importing Python modules when using NTFS-3g partition: "failed to map segment from shared object"

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, python, ntfs

I have a server where users' home folders lay in a NTFS partition (no Windows installed anywhere). Please notice this **cannot be changed**.

When I log as an user (not as root) and I start Python 2.7 or Python 3.6 prompt, I notice that trying to import modules usually throws the error:

> failed to map segment from shared object

For example, when I try to run `import numpy` inside Python 2.7 I get:

> Original error was:
>   /home/jorget/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.so:
>   failed to map segment from shared object

Trying the same in Python 3.6 gives me:

> Original error was:
>   /home/jorget/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
>   failed to map segment from shared object

Following some suggestions I found online that this problem could be related to the NTFS partition not being mounted with executable rights granted (for example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502156/what-are-possible-causes-of-failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object-operation) different but analogous question), I went to check if I was mounting my NTFS partition with `exec` and indeed I was. This is how the NTFS partition is being mounted:

> UUID=418F1E3E23E97C93 /media/datadisk/ ntfs-3g
>   auto,exec,user,permissions 0 0

So, it is being given executable rights. Yet, I still suspect the problem is related to that because when I start Python at the root prompt (not just `sudo python`), I can normally load modules installed within the root's python folders.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @mchid but that would not solve the issue for other users, right? I need a solution that works for others as well.